# Running script configured in Dockerfile after starting container as root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

What is the right way to start a container as root user?

I am trying to run a script on container startup.

Following is the starting of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

[ "$USER" = root ] || { echo "You must run $0 as root."; exit 1; }
```

Here are the contents of dockerfile.

```
USER root    
CMD "/service/run-dnscache.sh"
```

Command to build:

```
docker build --tag=friendlyhello --no-cache .
```

On running the container user seems to be non root. How do I run it as root?

```
vpp@VPP1:~/tmp$ docker run -it  --user root friendlyhello
You must run /service/run-dnscache.sh as root.


vpp@VPP1:~/tmp$ docker run -it  friendlyhello
You must run /service/run-dnscache.sh as root.
```

Comment: try `[ $(whoami) = root ]`

Comment: What does your complete Dockerfile look like? If the value of `$USER` isn't `root`, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right way to start a container as root user?

The default user INSIDE a container IS root. Typically container via the Docker daemon are running as root on the host machine as well.

What happens when you `$(whoami)` inside the container on start?